# Сравнить два списка и убрать совпадающие элементы

Tags: c#

Есть два условных класса:

```
public class One{
    public string Common {get;set;}
    ...}
public class Two{
    public string Common {get;set;}
    ...}
```

В данном примере показана одна переменная в каждом классе, она будет содержать одинаковые значения. Кроме этой переменной в каждом классе будет по 5 других, которые имеют разные, никак несвязанные значения.
Есть списки:

```
List<One> ListOne = new List<One>();
List<Two> ListTwo = new List<Two>():
```

Необходимо сравнить эти 2 списка, и убрать из них те элементы, у которых переменная Common совпадает (т.е. есть элементы в разных списках, у которых одинакова эта переменная).

На ум приходит только foreach, завернутый в другой foreach, но это перебор достаточного большого числа вариантов (в каждом списке будет около 50-ти элементов), есть ли более оптимизированный подход?

Comment: 50 элементов можно и перебрать за квадрат. Ну либо через Dictionary, но не факт, что получится лучше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вот так, но все равно "за кулисами" выполняются циклы:

```
List<One> ListOne = new List<One>();
List<Two> ListTwo = new List<Two>();
var result=ListOne.Join(ListTwo,ok=>ok.Common,ik=>ik.Common,(one,two)=>new {one,two}).ToList();
ListOne.RemoveAll(x=>result.Any(r => x==r.one));
ListTwo.RemoveAll(x=>result.Any(r => x==r.two));
```

P.S Есть еще вариант написать кастомный `EqualityComparer` для `object'ов`. Внутри приводить к нужному типу и выполнять сравнение. Затем идти циклом и добавлять в этот `HashSet` значения поочередно. Если оно не было добавлено, значит пересечении => удаляем элемент из исходных коллекций. Правда, не знаю, на сколько это будет быстрее. В теории должно.

Comment: Можно хлопнуть на `One` и `Two` интерфейс вроде `ICommon`, добавить в `Hashset<ICommon>` оба листа, а после в цикле достать значения, исходя из типа

Comment: Ок, материализовал.

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант:

```
var commons = ListOne.Select(o => o.Common).Intersect(ListTwo.Select(t => t.Common)).ToList();
// Тут, скорее всего, лучше будет вместо `ToList()` использовать
// `.ToHashSet()` если используется .NET 4.7.2+ или .NET Core 2.0+,
// либо `ToDictionary(x => x)` для более старых версий
ListOne.RemoveAll(o => commons.Contains(o.Common));
ListTwo.RemoveAll(t => commons.Contains(t.Common));
```

Внутри `Intersect` используется хэш-таблица, поэтому должно работать быстрее. Ну и не создаем лишних экземпляров анонимного класса.

Comment: А можно пруф по использованию HashSet? Что-то в MSDN об этом не пишут...

Comment: А и не напишут, т. к. это деталь реализации. Используется наиболее быстрый способ и если появится более быстрое решение, то реализация будет изменена. А то что там сейчас реально — можно посмотреть в [исходнике](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,879)

Comment: Хм... прикольно. Правда, там зачем-то сделали Set'ы вместо HashSet. Наверное, опять же что бы подменить реализацию.

Comment: Сильно не вникал, подозреваю, что используется упрощенный вариант, поэтому сделали так

Comment: Кстати, а у вас удаление не просядет в производительности? Ведь вы опять ищете по строкам, что медленно. А вот я в своем решении работаю со строками только 1 раз, а затем удаляю быстро по ссылкам.

Comment: Да, заметил уже, дописал комментарий. У вас, кстати, тоже будет 2 раза перебирать. Надо либо `.ToList`, но по нему поиск медленнее будет, либо, лучше `ToHashSet()`/`ToDictionary()`

Comment: @iluxa1810 так строки же по ссылкам сравниваются по дефолту?

Comment: @yolosora, у строк переопределено поведение. Они по символьно сравниваются.

Comment: @iluxa1810 точняк, если ссылки не равны то сравнивается посимвольно

Comment: @yolosora, возможно, перед посимвольным сравнением еще длинна проверяется, что бы заведомо выйти из цикла. По идее, строка должна знать свою длину.

Comment: @iluxa1810 так и есть, еще есть проверка операндов на null  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с hashset-ом дублируемых "ключей"

```
var dublicateKeys =
    new HashSet<string>(ListOne.Where(x => ListTwo.Exists(y => y.Common == x.Common)).Select(x => x.Common));
ListOne.RemoveAll(x => dublicateKeys.Contains(x.Common));
ListTwo.RemoveAll(x => dublicateKeys.Contains(x.Common));
```

Comment: У вас уже не `O(n^2)` даже, как в вопросе, а `O(n^2 + 2n)`. Автор спрашивал наоборот более оптимизированное решение хД Смотрите: мы идём по первому листу, для каждого значения запуская поиск во втором листе (за кулисами все тот же цикл внутри цикла, наши родимые `n^2` проходов). Нашли ключи дубликаты. И теперь идём заново по каждому из листов, удаляя элементы, чьи Common есть в HashSet. Поиск в HashSet - `O(1)`, так что запишем только проход по листам, а это лишние `2n`. Вот такие дела

Comment: @Kir_Antipov а где в вопросе O(n^2)?  Фраза "приходит на ум два вложенных прохода" - не является решением которое имеет смысл оценивать)

Comment: Почему не имеет?) Автор же просит более оптимизированный подход, а значит мы оцениваем то, что предложил он, и предлагаем что-то лучше ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov так он не предложил, если бы в вопросе содержался код с двумя вложенными проходами - его можно было бы оценить, а словами можно что угодно описать)

Comment: При грамотной расстановке сложность выполнения алгоритма, содержащего два цикла (один из которых - вложенный), равняется `O(n^2)`. Я согласен, что без кода оценить точно нельзя, но все же

Comment: @Kir_Antipov ну так пусть сначала кто-нибудь покажет проход с вложенным циклом, решающий поставленную задачу) а так не вижу смысла сферического коня в вакууме обсуждать, так можно написать вопрос "как написать самую быструю сортировку массива? приходит в голову только в 1 проход"

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, вложенные циклы не нужны, общие элементы двух списков находятся так (с использованием 2х `HashSet`): `var set1 = new HashSet<string>(list1); var set2 = new HashSet<string>(); foreach (var e in list2) if (set1.Remove(e)) set2.Add(e);` В `set2` будут все общие элементы

Comment: @АндрейNOP: я понимаю, что можно без вложенности. Я писал про то, что предлагал автор вопроса)